# How do I get the string obtained from get_clipboard function in godot?

Tags: godot

So When I use the `OS.get_clipboard()` function in godot it stores the clipboard value as string.

Now I want to show that on the screen in some way, but I can't.

`txt1 = OS.get_clipboard` does not work.

Comment: "does not work" is not a good way to describe a problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

**On the limitations of `OS.get_clipboard`:**

Calling `OS.get_clipboard()` will give you the contents of the clipboard as a string, if it is text. If you, for example, if you copied an image, `OS.get_clipboard()` will return empty string.

Also, depending on the platform `OS.get_clipboard()` might not work (mobile), or Godot might keep a clipboard independent of the operating system (web, might depend on the browser).

---

**Showing the content of the clipboard:**

I'd start with [`print`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-print), just to test that it is working:

```
print(OS.get_clipboard())
```

Another option is [`OS.alert`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-alert):

```
OS.alert(OS.get_clipboard())
```

However, if you want to set the text of a [`Label`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_label.html) or a [`TextEdit`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_textedit.html) or similar, you need to set its `text` property.

For example:

```
onready var label = get_node("Label")

func _something():
    label.text = OS.get_clipboard()
```

See also [`onready`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#onready-keyword).

This would also work:

```
func _something():
    $Label.text = OS.get_clipboard()
```

If you are not familiar with referencing other nodes, please refer to [Understanding node paths](http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/basics/getting_nodes/) and the documentation on [`get_node`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-get-node).

---

By the way, `OS.get_clipboard()` is the getter of the [`OS.clipboard`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-property-clipboard) property. You can simply do this:

```
onready var label = get_node("Label")

func _something():
    label.text = OS.clipboard
```

---

**Possible mistakes:**

If you do this:

```
onready var label = get_node("Label")

func _something():
    label = OS.get_clipboard()
```

You are replacing the reference to the node with the string. You will not see the contents of the clipboard either. *No errors or warnings.* This is not what you want.

If you want Godot to help you avoid such mistakes, annotate the types of your variables, for example, this tells Godot you are using a `Label`, and thus Godot will know that it should not be a string, and trying to set a string to it is an error (Godot can point this out without executing the code):

```
onready var label:Label = get_node("Label") # notice type annotation after ":"

func _something():
    label = OS.get_clipboard() # error
```

Or for a `TextEdit`:

```
onready var text:TextEdit = get_node("TextEdit") # notice type annotation after ":"

func _something():
    text = OS.get_clipboard() # error
```

See also [Static typing in GDScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html). *If you are on the "types are not necessary" camp, see [Ideology](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/ideology).*

---

I'll also remind you that when you want to call a method, you should not forget `()`. If you do, you would have an runtime error:

```
onready var label:Label = get_node("Label")

func _something():
    label.text = OS.get_clipboard # runtime error
```

*By runtime error, I mean it will fail when executing it.*

A way to avoid this mistake is to use the property instead:

```
onready var label:Label = get_node("Label")

func _something():
    label.text = OS.clipboard
```

---

Finally, to cover by bases, I'll say that if you store the content of your clipboard in some variable:

```
func _something():
    var txt1:String
    txt1 = OS.get_clipboard()
```

Well, what are you going to do with that variable? If you are not using it, Godot should be showing a `UNUSED_VARIABLE` warning in the editor.

*Remember to pay attention to the errors and warnings Godot shows you. And that types can help catch mistakes.*